# Retrieve Only the last values of a row in SQLITE with python 27

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using this code to get all data from a sqlite row, but I would like to retrieve only the last 30 entries.

```
import sqlite3
from matplotlib import pyplot
fig = pyplot.figure()

con = sqlite3.connect('growll.db')
con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select temp from GrowLLDados")
ar=[r[0] for r in cur.fetchall()]
```

Comment: How would one define "last"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like  `"select temp from GrowLLDados ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30"`

where `id` is an auto-incrementing counter or at least means the higher the number the more recent the entry ...